# why libvirt virdomain guest os mayignore the request to reboot or shutdown?

Tags: python, kvm, libvirt

the reboot function of virdomain class from libvirt-domain :

```
def reboot(self, flags=0):
        """Reboot a domain, the domain object is still usable thereafter, but
        the domain OS is being stopped for a restart.
        Note that the guest OS may ignore the request.
        Additionally, the hypervisor may check and support the domain
        'on_reboot' XML setting resulting in a domain that shuts down instead
        of rebooting.

        If @flags is set to zero, then the hypervisor will choose the
        method of shutdown it considers best. To have greater control
        pass one or more of the virDomainRebootFlagValues. The order
        in which the hypervisor tries each shutdown method is undefined,
        and a hypervisor is not required to support all methods.

        To use guest agent (VIR_DOMAIN_REBOOT_GUEST_AGENT) the domain XML
        must have <channel> configured.

        Due to implementation limitations in some drivers (the qemu driver,
        for instance) it is not advised to migrate or save a guest that is
        rebooting as a result of this API. Migrating such a guest can lead
        to a plain shutdown on the destination. """
        ret = libvirtmod.virDomainReboot(self._o, flags)
        if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainReboot() failed', dom=self)
        return ret
```

and my qemu/kvm vm doesn't response to the request to reboot or to shutdown , while it responds to request of reset. i want to know why and what can i do. thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which hypervisor you're using, so I'll assume QEMU/KVM in my answer.

There are two ways `shutdown` and `reboot` can work.

The default approach libvirt/QEMU takes is to inject an ACPI power button event. Most guest OS are built such that something will see the ACPI event and start a graceful shutdown, but this is not always the case. For reboot, libvirt will do the same ACPI power button injection, but when the guest has finished its shutdown sequence it will be reset so it boots again.

The second optional approach is to install the QEMU guest agent in the guest OS. You can then tell virsh to use the guest agent to trigger the shutdown/reboot. The guest agent is only available for certain OS though, modern Linux and windows if you have installed the virtio drivers package.

A `virsh reset` is completely different - this simply does an immediate reset of the virtual CPUs, causing instant restart of the guest, with no graceful shutdown process.

Comment: so you mean that the guest os just missed the acpi power button event in my situation? is it something wrong with the guest os?

Comment: Yeah, most likely nothing in the guest is looking for the ACPI event, and this generally indicates a misconfiguration.